# $x'_n\overset{w^\ast}{\to}0$ and $x_n\overset{w}{\to}0$ implies $\sup_m |x_m'|(|x_n|)\to 0$?

Tags: banach-spaces, weak-convergence, banach-lattices

If $x_n'$ is weak-$\ast$-ly null and $x_n$ is weakly null in a Banach lattice, do we always have

$$\sup_m |x_m'|(|x_n|)\to 0\,?$$

Thank you!

**Background:**

*Definition weak(-$\ast$) topology:*

On the dual $E'$ of a Banach lattice $E$ we define two topologies:

- $(x_n')$ in $E'$ converges to $x'$ in $E'$ weak-$\ast$-ly if and only if 
  $$\forall x\in E:x_n'(x)\to x'(x)\,,$$
- and it converges weakly if and only if 
  $$\forall x''\in E'':x''(x_n')\to x''(x)\,.$$

*Definition absolute value:*

The absolute value $|x|$ of an element of a Banach lattice is defined by $|x|=x\vee -x$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the notation $|x'_m|(|x_n)|). $  But an  infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$  is its own dual, and if $\{e_n:n\in \Bbb N\} $is an orthonormal Hilbert-space basis for $H$ then  the sequence $(e_n)_n$ converges weakly (and $ *$-weakly) to $0$ but for every $n$ we have $\sup_{m\in \Bbb N} e'_m(e_n)=e'_n(e_n)=1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, $|x|$ for $x$ in a Banach lattice is the absolute value, defined by $x\vee -x$. Your example is a counterexample for my claim, since the basis can be chosen positive.

Comment: If you want to read more on Hilbert space, I recommend A Hilbert Space Problem Book by Paul Halmos. It's a textbook. The style is to ask the reader to provide proofs. (Proofs $ are$ included, in the back of the book.)